# Problems with nextLine in java.

Tags: java, string

I have a question about the nextLine() method. I know that it sometimes does not read a line but reads a line separator e.g. `<enter>.` And therefore you need to call .nextLine() twice to "eat" the line separator and then get the next line. But how would this work in a loop? How could I get the last line of a file with this method? Should I use next() instead?

```
while ( fileStream1.hasNextLine() ){
        counterString = fileStream1.nextLine();
        ++lines;            
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested this and do you see a problem?

Comment: What do you think a line is?

Comment: the problem you have mentioned about nextline will happen in cases of next() and nextInt() with scanner I have never seen any issue with filestream.

Comment: @Ryan. This code works until i want to read the last line of a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can write something like this:

```
while ( fileStream1.hasNextLine() ){
    counterString = fileStream1.nextLine();
    if(!counterString.toString().equal("\n"))
       ++lines;            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
while ( fileStream1.hasNextLine() ){
    counterString = fileStream1.nextLine();

    if (counterString.Equals("\n") ||
        counterString.Equals("\r\n") ||
        counterString.Equals("\r")) {
        continue;
    }

    ++lines;            
}
```

To skip all lines that are just `\n`, `\r\n`, or `\r`

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking f.e. specifically about Scanner, next() will return the next token which is generally any word or character separated by white spaces. If you need non empty lines, it would probably look like this:

```
String s;
String lastLine;
int numOfNonEmptyLines = 0;

while(scan.hasNextLine()) {

    s = scan.nextLine();
    if(s.trim().isEmpty()) {
        continue;
    }

    lastLine = s;
    numOfNonEmptyLines++;
    //do whatever you want with the line
}

lastLine //this is the last line...
```